# OS X: Git with client certificates rejected

Tags: git, curl, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite, client-certificates

We access our Git server with client certificates by adding the following lines to ~/.gitconfig

```
[http]
        sslCAInfo = /path/to/git-ca.crt
        sslCert = /path/to/git-client.crt
        sslKey = /path/to/git-client.pem
```

This works fine on Linux, Windows and OS X <= 10.8 with exactly the same files. When I try it on OS X 10.10, I'm getting the following error:

```
bash-3.2$ git fetch
fatal: unable to access 'https://ourserver:12345/repository.git/': SSL: Can't load the certificate "/path/to/git-client.crt" and its private key: OSStatus -25299
```

The problem happens with `git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)` as well as with `git version 2.0.1`.

**Update**
After removing the corresponding item from the KeyChain, I'm getting following crash:

```
bash-3.2$ git fetch
2014-11-17 09:58:51.257 git-remote-https[2787:12194] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9828164c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f91c6de objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98125068 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 360
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98124a2d CFArrayCreate + 141
    4   libcurl.4.dylib                     0x00007fff8f75169e darwinssl_connect_common + 2089
    5   libcurl.4.dylib                     0x00007fff8f75073a Curl_ssl_connect_nonblocking + 36
    6   libcurl.4.dylib                     0x00007fff8f719673 Curl_http_connect + 77
    7   libcurl.4.dylib                     0x00007fff8f727977 Curl_protocol_connect + 129
    8   libcurl.4.dylib                     0x00007fff8f739cef multi_runsingle + 799
    9   libcurl.4.dylib                     0x00007fff8f73993d curl_multi_perform + 170
    10  git-remote-https                    0x0000000109815c8a step_active_slots + 25
    11  git-remote-https                    0x0000000109815cfb run_active_slot + 77
    12  git-remote-https                    0x0000000109817621 http_request + 459
    13  git-remote-https                    0x0000000109816148 http_request_reauth + 34
    14  git-remote-https                    0x0000000109813f76 discover_refs + 476
    15  git-remote-https                    0x00000001098131e4 main + 1556
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff94bd25c9 start + 1
    17  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

After this crash, the certificate entry has reoccurred in the Keychain. The strange thing is, that on OS X 10.8 nothing will be added to my Keychain while fetching from the repository.

**Update 2**
When I try the same on OS X 10.9, I'm getting following error:

```
bash-3.2$ git fetch
fatal: unable to access 'https://ourserver:12345/repository.git/': SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
```

**Update 3**
I can successfully connect with `openssl` using these certificates, even on OS X 10.9:

```
bash-3.2$ openssl s_client -connect ourserver:12345 -cert /path/to/git-client.crt -key /path/to/git-client.pem
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=de/O=companyca/CN=internal-ca
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=de/O=companyserv/CN=smart
   i:/C=de/O=companyca/CN=internal-ca
 1 s:/C=de/O=companyca/CN=internal-ca
   i:/C=de/O=companyca/CN=internal-ca
---
Server certificate
...
<----------------------snip---------------------->
...
---
SSL handshake has read 2348 bytes and written 1360 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: E5873AF43D24CEE6529178B4EFD7FE3368711DF1BFBC6CA89C50F8D39DE0B014
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: <**********>
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1416486728
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
closed
```

The problem looks similar to [this one for GitHub](https://superuser.com/questions/721778), but we are using self-signed certificates.

Comment: 25299 means "The specified item already exists in the keychain". Maybe you copied a public key twice into the crt files?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I removed the item from the KeyChain.

Comment: @ThomasS. Well, did it solve your problem?

Comment: No, see above the update. I'm now getting the crash.

Comment: How did you create `.pem` file?

Comment: I've got it from my admin. And as said, it works on all OS X < 10.9, Linux and Windows.

Comment: Check the CA certificate is not expired. Then check that it is included in `.pem`

Comment: It is not expired. It still works on OS X < 10.9, Linux and Windows.

Comment: Have you run first aid on your keychain?

Comment: No, what does "first aid on keychain" means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you are facing the same problem as in [this docker issue](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/573) where they conclude it's likely a bug in OSX curl.

In some [other post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/apple-cdsa/2008/Apr/msg00030.html) they suggest, that this could be caused by certificate serial number either being 1 or being too large to fit in 32 bits.

On your OS X 10.9 case, I think "Invalid Certificate" should be solved by adding the certificate to system key chain as trusted (discussed in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121817/how-to-fix-curl-60-ssl-certificate-invalid-certificate-chain-when-using-sudo)).

[This post](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2013-10/0036.html) describes some changes in OS X curl, which seem to be related. In my understanding, it might be solution to switch to different [curl implementation](http://brewformulas.org/Curl) (but likely that only could work if git would also be installed using brew).

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the information I found in the links did help solve the problem. I had to switch from https with client certificates to SSH on OS X 10.9+.

Answer (score 2):

As Michal already mentioned it is a OSX curl bug. A possible solution would be to **install a git version which does not rely the osx curl implementation**

1. Install macports: https://www.macports.org/install.php
2. $port -v selfupdate
3. $port install git

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no option because we can't expect macports being installed on the end-user's machines.

Comment: doesn't work for me on 10.11 .. I used home-brew but it still fails